# Populate Textboxes with VLookup from Other Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I'm a new VBA user and I've run into a bit of a roadblock on my first real UserForm task. I am trying to populate two separate UserForm textboxes with information from VLookup in VBA. The point is to choose two workbooks by path/filename, and run a VLookup based on the ActiveCell in the open workbook. The end goal is to have the user choose which value is preferred, select it, and the new value will be stored in the open workbook. Right now I have a ClickButton that runs the macro (bear with me), and this is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim PR As String
Dim Eval2 As String
Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim extwbk As Workbook
Dim x As Range


Set book1 = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\ReviewBook.xlsx")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100")


PR = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
Eval2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PR, x, 5, False)
extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

Textbox.Text = PR
FilePath1.Text = FP1
FP2 = FilePath2.Text

TextBox2.Text = Eval2

End Sub
```

I've had to clean this up from what's actually in my VBA, let me know if anything doesn't work or is unclear. I keep getting Error Code '1004.' Like I said I'm just trying to get "TextBox2.Text" to be the value from a VLookup. Thanks for any clarifications or help!

Answer (score 1):

When you say error code 1004, I am going to assume it tells you something like "Unable to get VLookup property" or something. If so, then that means your VLookup is returning an error, which will cause your code to stop executing. To fix this, try incorporating:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    '...your code...

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       TextBox2.Text = Eval2
    Else
       Msgbox "VLookup did not return a value"
    End If
```

into your code to see if that works. This is the best suggestion I can give without any data or the full module to do a test but give it a shot anyways.

Comment: Alternatively, use `Application.VLookup` and declare `Eval2` as a `Variant`; if VLookup fails, `Eval2` will contain an error value that you can validate with `If IsError(Eval2) Then` before using it as a `String`.

Comment: You were correct, this did allow the code to run properly. However, I cant seem to ever get the VLookup to work. I have even tried searching inside a copy of the same spreadsheet, which should guarantee a match, with no luck. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing I can really suggest without seeing some sample data/code. Would you be able to edit your question to provide a minimal working sample of your error?